# Mongoose Query to Match Object ID with User ID, then display in DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm pretty new to this, so apologies if I'm not using the right jargon. I am using Node, Express, MongoDB, and Mongoose.

I have a mongo model for Recipe:

```
var recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    url: String,
    notes: String,
    image: String,
    ingredients: [String],
    author: {
       id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User'
       },
       username: String
    }
});
```

and a model for User:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  recipes: [
  {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Recipe'
  }
]
});
```

When I display recipes, I want one button to show up if the current user has added a specific recipe to their recipes object, and a different button to appear if they have not. My client-side code has access to a currentUser_id which I could use to query that user's recipes and see if the current recipe is a match, but I'm a bit lost on how to do that (client side or server side?), and then pass that information to the DOM to update a button.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to this type of problems is to have a server that responds to a certain API. For example:

calling: `http://yourserver.com/recipes/<user_id>` - will return a json with all the recipes for that user.

Another idea: `http://yourserver.com/u/<user_id>/recipe/<recipe_id>` - will return true or false whether that user_id has that recipe_id.

All access to the DB will be performed on the express method that handles it.

Comment: what if these routes already exist in the app for other functions?

Comment: Well, you can always add more routes as you see fit.